# Unable to update values in Flutter using setState

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, provider

I have a list named activityList mapped to ActivityDataModel class and I have been using Provider flutter package to receive all values from firestore. I have also have been using a DatePicker package to select dates.

So, when I press on a date and the date is changed, I want to show the total activity data for the day.

In onDateChange of the DatePicker, I use forEach loop to cycle through the list items and extract each value and then compute the total value. ie. each list item has "coins" variable and then use "totalCoins" variable to store total number of coins, after cycling through each "coins" variable in the list item.

But the totalCoins or any total...variable does not seem to be updating for some reason. I used setState to update the values in the UI but that does not seem to work.

### ActivityDataModel class

```
class ActivityDataModel {
int score, coins, time, calories;
String dateTime;

ActivityDataModel(
  {required this.score,
  required this.coins,
  required this.calories,
  required this.time,
  required this.dateTime});
}
```

---

### MainActivity.dart

```
class ActivityHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActivityHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = "/activityhome";

  @override
  State<ActivityHome> createState() => _ActivityHomeState();
}

class _ActivityHomeState extends State<ActivityHome> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  int coins = 0, score = 0, calories = 0;
  double time = 0.0;
  int totalCoins = 0, totalScore = 0, totalCalories = 0;
  double totalTime = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context, listen: true);
    List<ActivityDataModel?>? activityList =
        Provider.of<List<ActivityDataModel?>?>(context, listen: true);
    // print(activityList?.elementAt(2)?.coins.toString());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black, //change your color here
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Activity",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.sp,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0.r),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DatePicker(
              DateTime(2022, 9, 9, 0, 0,
                  0), //DateTime.now(), // replace with Joining date
              height: 100,
              width: 80,
              initialSelectedDate:
                  DateTime(2022, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0), //DateTime.now(),
              selectionColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              daysCount: 10,
              onDateChange: (date) {
                selectedDate = date;
                DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                activityList?.forEach((activityData) {
                  DateTime activityDate =
                      dateFormat.parse(activityData?.dateTime ?? "0");
                  if (activityDate.day == selectedDate.day) {
                    print("true");
                    print(activityDate.day);
                    print(selectedDate.day);
                    coins = activityData!.coins;
                    calories = activityData.calories;
                    score = activityData.score;
                    time = (activityData.time / 60);

                    setState(() {
                    totalCoins += coins;
                    totalCalories += calories;
                    totalScore += score;
                    totalTime += time;
                    });
                  } else {
                     setState(() {
                    totalCoins = 0;
                    totalScore = 0;
                    totalCalories = 0;
                    totalTime = 0;
                     });
                  }
                });
                setState(() {});
                print(totalCoins);
                print(totalCalories);
                print(totalScore);
                print(totalTime);
              },
            ),
            VerticalSpace(10.h),
            const Divider(
              height: 1,
              thickness: 0.3,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            VerticalSpace(10.h),
            ActivityCardWidget(
              coins: totalCoins.toString(),
              time: totalTime.toStringAsFixed(1),
              calories: totalCalories.toString(),
              score: totalScore.toString(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The correct o/p only shows for one date and the rest shows zero.

Comment: This seems to be related to your if statement. Since you set an initial date, the first one sets fine, but after that this statement never ends up being true and so it skips and goes to your else statement:

```
activityDate.day == selectedDate.day
```
I would do some debugging and figure out what changes you need to make to your dates so that you can enter that if statement properly.

Comment: No, it does show true for the condition but somehow doesn't add to the total values